# Como editar algo salvo no banco de dados em Python

Tags: html, python, django

Estou precisando pesquisar um aluno por nome ou cpf que está salvo no Banco de dados e recuperar esse mesmo aluno em um formulário pra poder edita-lo e posteriormente estar salvando de novo. Estou usando o Django como framework. Eu já fiz um html criando o campo de pesquisa

```
{% extends 'aluno/index4.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <body>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                <form class="input-group" action="." method="get">
                    <input type="text" name="pesquisar_por" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar por...">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
                    </span>
                </form>
            </div>
    </body>
{% endblock %}
```

Porém não estou sabendo integrar isso com a view para assim estar renderizando o formulário pra edição. Alguém pode dar um help?

Answer (score 0):

Resumidamente, você vai usar o `render()` para que quando sua `view` seja chamada por uma `url`, após fazer o trabalho atribuído a ela, a mesma responda ao usuário com um template (como o html que você mesmo exemplificou acima).

[Aqui](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.0/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render) você vai encontrar uma breve explicação sobre o comando que citei acima, inclusive com um exemplo. Recomendo que você de uma olhada na documentação do Django sobre [templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/). Por ser algo bem longo e massante de se ler em primeiro momento, mas posso garantir que agiliza muito a vida ler a documentação antes de começar a desenvolver.